# How do I shut down code collaborator server?

Tags: code-collaborator

I am trying to reset my admin password using the instructions given [here](http://community.smartbear.com/t5/Collaborator/What-if-I-forgot-my-Collaborator-admin-password/td-p/71280). The first step is to shut down the collaborator server. And I can't seem to figure out how to shut it down properly, apart from going to Windows services and actually stopping the service from there.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended up doing this by shutting down the corresponding Windows service.